# Selecting items from a dropdown menu with RSelenium

Tags: r, web-scraping, drop-down-menu, html-select, rselenium

I am using the code snippet below  to select an item from a dropdown menu but it's not working consistently:

```
#OUTPUT TO
  Output <- remDr$findElement(using = 'id', value = 'ddlOutputType')
  Output$clickElement()[enter image description here][1]
  #CSV
  option4 = Output$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//*/option[@value = 'T']")
  option4$clickElement()
```

The browser often just goes with the default value in the dropdown instead of the value I want. For reference, I have attached a screenshot of the dropdown menu I'm selecting from--*@value = T* corresponds to *Text File (CSV)*. The default value for the dropdown menu is *R*, which corresponds to *Report Viewer*. I cannot provide you with the URL because it is a restricted website that requires user credentials, but I have also pasted the relevant portion of the webpage's HTML below:

```
<select name="ddlOutputType" id="ddlOutputType">
    <option value="R">Report Viewer</option>
    <option value="T">Text File (CSV)</option>

</select>
```

Comment: Provide a reproducible example, provide website address.

Comment: Unfortunately, the website is not publicly available; you need user credentials to log in.